# What condition is need for exponential equation to have unique solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, exponential-function

### Goal: what condition we need so that there is a unique solution of $A \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times N}$

$$e^{A} = e^{\Lambda}$$ where $\Lambda \in \mathbb{\Lambda}^{N\times N}$ is known, it is complex diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not unique. For all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ and $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ we have $e^z=e^{z+2\pi ik}$. From here it easily follows that the solution $A=\Lambda$ is not unique. For example, if $\Lambda$ is diagonal then you can define $B$ by adding $2\pi i$ to every element on the main diagonal and you will get $e^B=e^{\Lambda}$.

Comment: thanks. So can we show that the solution $A$ is not unique but only different by something related to 2pi?

Comment: It's even more complicated. For example $exp(\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -2\pi \\ 2\pi & 0 \end{bmatrix})$ is the identity matrix, same as $exp(\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix})$. So the solution is not necessary unique even over $\mathbb{R}$.